# cakephp mysql uppercase table error

Tags: mysql, cakephp-1.3

I'm getting this error because `Categories` table doesn't exist but it does!, the problem is the uppercase at the beginning, now if I change ALL the table's names to uppercase on the first letter the problem is gone but I don't want to change all the table's names, the problem was when I committed new code but I don't know what I did and I think is MySql configuration problem, any idea how to fix this problem? THANKS!!!!

Error:

> SQL Error: 1146: Table 'product_phpfogapp_com.Categories' doesn't
>   exist [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 681]

Thanks you!!!

Comment: Convention in Cake seems to be for tables with lower-case names: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions Have you overridden that somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YourModelName extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'your_table_name'; // This model uses a database table 'your_table_name'
}
```